# Do i need a gateway and subnet mask for an embedded system that does nothing other wait for incoming traffic?

Tags: networking, tcp, embedded

I've got an embedded system that just sits their waiting for incoming TCP/IP comms. It's got a static IP address. Do I need to actually set a subnet mask and gateway address as the system NEVER talks out other than when it is talked to?

If I do, please explain why.

Thanks,

Stuart

Comment: TCP requires bidirectional communication, so yes, you need a gateway and mask because it does communicate out.

Comment: But doesn't the routing information come with the incoming comms. Just that the system works perfectly through a gateway regardless of the subnet mask or gateway address. We have devices on our internal network here where we've just set a Static IP address and all that we've done is forward ports on our ADSL router. With this the outside world can communicate with this.

Comment: Then you are not using TCP as your question says. Likely, it is using UDP. For a device to send traffic off its network, as TCP would require, it would need to know the gateway and mask. A device compares the masked source and destinations addresses to see if the destination is on the same LAN. if not, it will send the traffic to the configured gateway layer-2 address. Routing information does not come in the traffic, each packet is routed on its own, regardless of any previous traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You can sometimes cheat and do such a thing with IP.  The mac addresses should be there, assuming no broadcast, and the ip header has the source/destination, you can flip both around and the ports.  You would still need to respond to the ARP looking for you, but the cheat is not sending an ARP looking for them basically ignoring the timeout.  To do it correctly you need to keep a table locally and a timer and if you have never seen that ip address or the last time you saw it was more than a minute ago or whatever your timeout is, then you need to ARP for it to be able to respond.  TCP is a much larger pain in the ..., with UDP you can do this kind of thing quite easily, swap macs, swap ip, swap ports, fill in the payload, checksum if you want or not, and send it back.  Put code in to respond to the ARP.  Dont see off hand why TCP would be any different.

Now assuming you are talking about some operating system, embedded or otherwise with a full stack, then that stack is likely going to want that information, but it is operating system/stack specific as to whether you can put bogus numbers in or not for situations where they dont need to be examined to respond to a particular connection.  Of course that is not a programming question and this is a programming site, so I assume that is not what you are asking.